# Can I choose which level I'll go in?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

Sometimes, when starting anew game in Wrath of the Lamb, I'll find myself in the cellar rather than the basement. Ditto when going down a level.

What determines which level I'll go in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything to determine what floor you end up on as far as anyone knows.  It's random.  Going into Utero instead of The Womb doesn't seem to make a difference, however.